# How to resolve setWifiEnabled(bool) deprecated method into Android Q?

Tags: java, android, android-10.0

In my case, I have existing code for enabling wifi. Here I am getting code depreciation at `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` and `setWifiEnabled(true)` in Android Q api level 29.  Below code is working fine in old version but depreciation happen only on `api 29`. How to resolve it with help of version condition.

**Enable Wifi Code**

```
private void enableWifi(Context context, String ssid) {
        if(webWifiStateListener != null) {
            context.unregisterReceiver(webWifiStateListener);
        }
        webWifiStateListener = new WifiStateListener(ssid);
        context.registerReceiver(webWifiStateListener,
                new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)); // CONNECTIVITY_ACTION Deprecated Android Q
        webWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true); // Deprecated Android Q
    }
```

Comment: The only solution I found was to target SDK 28, unfortunately. My APP is a night clock that must stay on all night, so it disables about everything to save energy and prevent sounds. In particular, WiFi, location, bluetooth, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Android Q won't let apps turn Wi-Fi on and off. You can use something like this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Panel

Comment: I have added settings panel but I have to do `private boolean connectToSSID(String ssid)` also `private class WifiStateListener extends BroadcastReceive`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in Android Q:

```
Intent panelIntent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.Panel.ActionWifi);
StartActivityForResult(panelIntent,1);
```

Don't use:

```
webWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true); // Deprecated Android Q
```